# How to run cypress in mobile view wrt functionality not just viewport?

Tags: cypress

I have a web application that behaves separately on web and mobile. For instance, on web the entire form is shown on one screen only, while on mobile, the form is divided into two steps. After filling the first part, the user clicks on `proceed` button and moves to next page

I am using cypress to test the web app and everything runs fine there. However, if I test the mobile view by adding this line

```
    cy.viewport('iphone-5');
```

It does show that the test is running on the viewport of iphone-5, however it is only being responsive, not changing functionality wise. As in I see the form on a single page only, the responsiveness does it affected but the form not shown on two separate screens as it should on mobile. How do I make sure it also changes functionality wise? What am I missing?

How do I test the app on mobile as if it is actually running on a mobile device not just in terms of responsiveness.

Comment: Is your web app public. If yes can you please add the URL ?

Comment: No, it is not public

Comment: How does your web app technically verify that it is being accessed on a mobile device? Maybe you could add details about that to the question.

Comment: It identifies it on the basis of view port only, it checks the view port of the device, sets a ```mobile``` variable to true and based on this variable renders the output. But I do not seem to understand how can I put such conditions in cypress.

Comment: Have you tried passing a `userAgent` header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
describe('Test Suite', () => {
  before(() => {
    cy.viewport('iphone-5')
  })

  it('Some Test', () => {
    cy.visit(url, {
      headers: {
        'user-agent':
          'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36',
      },
    })
  })
})
```

Along with `cy.visit()` we are passing now an `userAgent` header. You can get a list of user-agent lists from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent). Currently I have used the userAgent for `Chrome UA string`.

You can add the userAgent in your `cypress.json` file as well:

```js
{
  userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36'
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to use this in the before method so that I do not have to write it with cy.visit?

Comment: You can add this as a configuration as well in your `cypress.json` file but then it is applicable to your entire project. Updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you, but the header request only gets added for the url I am passing, if I click or navigate to another screen I lose the headers. How can I make sure the headers are passed with every request

Comment: The first request which I use with cy.visit runs as expected and I can see the mobile functionality, then I click on a button to navigate to another screen and again there I see desktop behavior. How to persist the user-agent sent in header? TIA

Answer (score 1):

Try adjusting the user agent on the `window:before:load` event, I seem to recall this is the way to do it.

```js
beforeEach(() => {
  cy.viewport('iphone-5')
  cy.on('window:before:load', (win) => {
    Object.defineProperty(win.navigator, 'userAgent', {
       value: 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 11_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/604.1.38 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Mobile/15A372 Safari/604.1',
      });
  })
})
```

Note also `beforeEach()` is preferred, I think there is a reset between tests.

---

User agent is only useful if the app actually check it, but you mention in comments that it identifies it on the basis of view port only.

If you want check the `isMobile` variable in the test, you can (temporarily) expose it from the app

```js
// app code after mobile indicator is set

if (window.Cypress) { // only in a test
  window.Cypress.isMobile = isMobile
}
```

```js
// test
cy.viewport('iphone-5')
cy.visit('/')
cy.wrap(Cypress.isMobile).should('eq', true)
```